# Stuck in a loop while performing mysqldump

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a database (not by me) with ~140000 images, and only some (~3500 or so) are to be saved. I am trying to do this using mysqldump, but somehow I seem to be stuck in a loop. Even when performing this procedure over ~ 10 images to be saved, the sql dump file indefinitely grows in size.

Here is one of the database tables, named images.

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
    `imageID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `runID_fk` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `sequenceID_fk` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `cameraID_fk` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `data` LONGBLOB NULL,
    `timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `name` TEXT NULL,
    `type` TEXT NULL,
    `pcadata` LONGBLOB NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`imageID`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

If `type` is set to `perm`, then the image is to be saved. Here is my mysqldump command:

```
mysqldump -u root --verbose -p (database name) images --where="imageID IN (SELECT imageID WHERE type='perm' AND imageID BETWEEN (some number) and (some number))">\location\backup.sql
```

What is possibly wrong with this command?

EDIT: If I update the command as

```
mysqldump -u root --single-transaction=true --verbose -p (database name) images --where="imageID IN (SELECT imageID FROM images WHERE type='perm' AND imageID BETWEEN (some number) and (some number))">\location\backup.sql
```

then things seem fine. I basically added "FROM images" in the inner query, and added lock table option in the `mysqldump` option. But I would still like to know the cause of the indefinite loop caused by the first command.

Comment: Mystery.  File a bug report if you like:  bugs.mysql.com